# How to Write Getters and Setters for C-Style String Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am not allowed to use `std::string`, and required to use `C-Style` string arrays.

I am working on the Getters and Setters for the string arrays but encountered the following errors:

> error: prototype for void Unit::SetName(const char*, unsigned int) does not match any in class 'Unit'
>
> error: candidate is: void Unit::SetName(const char**, unsigned int)

Below is my code snippet.

```
#ifndef UNIT_H
#define UNIT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
const unsigned UnitNameSize = 10;

class Unit {
public:
  Unit();
  Unit( const char * nam, unsigned cred );

  const char* GetName() const;
  void SetName( const char *nam[], unsigned UnitNameSize);

  friend ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Unit & U );
  friend istream & operator >>( istream & input, Unit & U );

private:
  char name[UnitNameSize];
  int credits;
};

inline const char* Unit::GetName() const{
  return name;
}

//error-ed set method
inline void Unit::SetName( const char* nam , unsigned namSize){
  name[] = nam[namSize];
}
#endif
```

Comment: `std::strncpy`?

Comment: Also, the C++ header is `<cstring>`, `<string.h>` has been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: Do you see the second `*` in `const char **` in the line `error: candidate is: void Unit::SetName(const char**, unsigned int)`?

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you pass an array as a function parameter?

Comment: May I know how can I use `std::strncpy`?

Comment: "I am not allowed..." -- {walks away screaming in rage} -- [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: "How can I use `std::strncpy`?" -- By `#include <cstring>`, and [with care, please](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). That particular function has unintuitive behavior both before *and* after reaching the maximum number of characters to copy.

Comment: "_I am not allowed to use `std::string`_" - In that case, the first thing I'd do is to write my own separate string class with the basic functionality needed for this, and probably some future, projects where `std::string` is not accepted. When that string class is done, this question sort of goes away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The first thing **I'd** do is find a *competent* lecturer that doesn't teach how to build your own wheels as a "good" intro to driving school. Next thing you know, we teach people how to design a CPU instruction set as the first lesson of a Python course. C++ has a very good standard library, one big advantage of which is that *you should not have to know the first thing about C arrays*. Not in a beginner course. And your `std::string` replacement won't be a basis to teach you about iterators, `<algorithm>`, character traits, or allocators...

Comment: @DevSolar part of the problem is that C++ is used sometimes in courses that teach low level concepts, like data-structures, pointers, arrays etc., and too often the lecturer completely forgets to mention that the course is not about C++. A course about assembler can use Python as a tool, but of course that does not make it a course on Python

Comment: @idclev463035818: Then use, and label that course as, C. That's appropriate for that kind of work. The "teaching" of "C++" by having the students go through "tool deprivation" not only hurts the students in their learning efforts, it hurts the language in amassing a reputation for being "hard" when it really isn't, **and** is hurting people in the workplace because too many students will keep implementing things "the C way" because they never learned better, or had mentally shut off by the time "the real stuff" was taught. I'd rather rant about those cases than assuming a mislabeled course...

Comment: @DevSolar :-) Indeed - but replacing a lecturer may be hard so _if_ you are forced to deal with strings without having `std::string` available, making your own as a separate class could be useful. At least one wouldn't have to mix in a lot of code dealing with C strings in the other classes, like OP:s `Unit` class.

Comment: You can convert `std::string` to C-Style string just invoke `.c_str()`. Inventing your own string class is not good.

Comment: @MasterJames If you are not allowed to use `std::string` it's better to invent your own string class than to deal with plain C strings in every class that needs strings.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the length of the name in your class is a fixed length, the easiest way to do this [`std::strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). That would work as follows:

```
inline void Unit::SetName (char const * name) {
  std::strncpy(this->name, name, UnitNameSize);
  // Ensure name member ends in null-terminator, 
  // even if new name length is >= UnitNameSize.
  this->name[UnitNameSize - 1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: is it okay if I use the following `strncpy` implementations without `->`?

Comment: `void SetName( const char* nam, unsigned UnitNameSize);`

Comment: `inline void Unit::SetName( const char* nam, unsigned nameSize ){
  strncpy( name, nam, nameSize );
}`

Comment: @gymcode This way you need to check if `nameSize` exceeds `UnitNameSize`

Comment: @gymcode I'm assuming that the input `name` is a "regular" C-style string, i.e. null-terminated. In which case passing in it's length is redundant. And would also force you to compare the passed in length vs `UnitNameSize`, as said by @Odysseus.

Comment: @gymcode: Of course it's OK to use a different name for the parameter than for the member variabe. For this very reason, a common coding style is to use a special prefix / suffix for (all) member variables (instead of using weird abbreviations). Like an underscore suffix: `name_` for the member, `name` for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pointing to the fact that SetName's declaration and definition's signature does not match. In one you are expecting pointer to c string in the other a c string. Also, your SetName function is wrong, it would attempt to access the char pass the end of the string of the param.
 Why can't you use std:: string?

Comment: Maybe it's the rule that they should follow. I'm assuming that this is a sort of assignment or something.